# How to decode Google API access token

Tags: node.js, jwt, google-oauth, google-api-js-client

I have created SPA login using Google api , which returns `access_token` and `id_token`

While it is relatively easy to decode the id token using the following code, on a Node.js backend, using **google-auth-library**:

```
 gapiAuthLibrary.verifyIdToken({
        idToken: token,
        audience: GOOGLE_OAUTH_TEST_APP_CLIENT_IDD
    });
```

There is no clear way to decode access_token, which is much more reliable.

What do I miss?

Comment: I don't know google tokens, but  I guess it might be an [opaque or reference token](https://openiddict.github.io/openiddict-documentation/guide/token-formats.html). Both formats are not intended to be decoded by you.